# Is there a shorter way of solving this using higher order functions? Perhaps the filter method?

Tags: javascript

Return a new array without the most expensive thing in the list. Your function should preserve the order of the items in this array. The code is correct and so is the output. I don't have a lot of exp with HOF so I would like to see how this can be done using the filter method.

```
    function removeMostExpensive(list) {
  var expensive = list[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].price > expensive.price) {
      expensive = list[i];
    }
  }
  var newList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i] !== expensive) {
          newList.push(list[i]);
    }
  }
  return newList;
}
console.log(removeMostExpensive([
  {
    item: "rice",
    price: 12.75,
    weightInPounds: 20
  },
  {
    item: "chicken",
    price: 6.99,
    weightInPounds: 1.25
  },
  {
    item: "celery",
    price: 3.99,
    weightInPounds: 2
  },
  {
    item: "carrots",
    price: 2.85,
    weightInPounds: 2
  },
  {
    item: "green beans",
    price: 2.55,
    weightInPounds: 2
  }
]));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the most expensive item by mapping the array to the prices and calling `Math.max` on it. Then filter the array by whether the current item being iterated over has that price:

```
function removeMostExpensive(list) {
    const max = Math.max(...list.map(obj => obj.price));
    return list.filter(obj => obj.price !== max);
}
```

That's assuming that your current code works - that if more than one item is tied for the same highest expense, all should be removed.

Comment: Using array.reduce instead of using Math.max and map is a much more efficient solution to find the max. No reason to iterate the array twice and create a whole new array of size N just to find the max.

Comment: Yeah, my approach does create an extra intermediate array, but unless one's dealing with an unreasonably huge number of items, it'll be a non-issue on modern hardware - readability is a far greater concern in the vast majority of situations, at least in my experience

Comment: Totally agreed, JS is hardly a performant language, and shouldn't be used for time sensitive problems, but not sure why everyone is so afraid of array reduce.. It's so powerful and honestly not that complex.

Answer (score 2):

There won't be much difference with `filter` but you can do both operation ( finding max & returning the array without max ) on same loop.

Solution without extra memory allocation:

```js
function removeMostExpensive(list) {
  const newList = [];
  let expensive = list[0];

  list.filter((item, index) => {
    if(item.price > expensive.price) {
       expensive = list[index];
    }
    // because the expensive will always change if above condition is true
    if(item !== expensive) {
      newList.push(list[index]);
    }
  });
  return newList;
}
```

I have only compared your output from the sample input with the above modified version of code. Not sure if this will pass all the test cases but you can simplify your code this way.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for higher functions. You can use a combination of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). `reduce` often comes in powerful, but one needs to wrap the mind around first.

The `console.log` is only to observe how it works.

```
function removeMostExpensive(list) {
  var newList = [...list];

  var reducer = function(a, c, i) { 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(a) + ', ' + JSON.stringify(c) + ', ' + i); 
    if (c && c.price > a.price) {
      a.price = c.price;
      a.index = i;
    }  
    return a; 
  }

  var maxInfo = newList.reduce(reducer, {price: -1});
  newList.splice(maxInfo.index, 1);

  return newList;
}
```

While `reduce` iterates through the array, it will collect a) the biggest value and b) the index of the particular biggest value. The index is then ready and used for `splice`.